# Get files from javascript function

Tags: python, selenium

Need to download the files using Python from a [site](https://www.dnb.no/bedrift/markets/analyser/arkiv/anbefalteaksjer.html).
The list of files is generated with the JS function.

```
//<![CDATA[




$(document).ready(function(){
        var url='/portalfront/portal/list/list-files.php';
        var data={paths:'/portalfront/nedlast/no/markets/analyser-rapporter/norske/anbefalte-aksjer/|usename=Anbefalte aksjer|count=52'};

        var myElement=Portal.getLocalizedString("PostError") || 'error';
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:url,
            data:data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(jdata) {           
                if(jdata.status.match(/ok/i)){
                    myElement='';
                    $.each(jdata.data, function(messageIndex, message) {
                         myElement+='<p class="moduleItemPdf"><a target="_blank" href="'+message['path']+'" class="moduleItem">'+message['date']+' '+message['name']+'</a></p>';
                    });             
                }
            },
            complete:function(xhr,status) {
                var _id="div#"+"anbefalte-aksjer-arkiv";
                $(_id).append(myElement);
                if($(_id).closest('div#column_right').length==0){
                    var e=parseInt($(_id).height());
                    var _height=40+(0 * 20);
                    $(_id).closest('.moduleWhite').height(e+_height);
                    Portal.alignModulesVertically();
                }
            }
        });
});



            //]]>
```

And the poroblem is that I'm not familiar with JS.
I suppose that I have to use Selenium for this task and I think it should lool like that:

```
url = 'https://www.dnb.no/bedrift/markets/analyser/arkiv/anbefalteaksjer.html'
wd = webdriver.Firefox()
wd.get(url)
links_script = wd.execute_script(js script)
```

1. What should I put in the function?
2. What should I get? Will it be html?
3. How can I download this file? I mean how can I receive its links?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium to get list of files, then use Python to  download it.
Could you try code below?

Code:

```
def download_file(url):
    local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
            if chunk: 
                f.write(chunk)
    return local_filename

wd.get('https://www.dnb.no/bedrift/markets/analyser/arkiv/anbefalteaksjer.html')
time.sleep(5) 

pdfLinks = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector('.moduleItemPdf > a')

for linkElement in pdfLinks:
    filename=download_file(linkElement.get_attribute("href"))
    print(filename)



time.sleep(5)
wd.quit()
```

Comment: I've just updated this answer with the full source code. Please note that you have to create the web driver 'wd' before this code.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, I have just landed in this question but I'm interested in the solution: what software should I install in order to run this script? Or where can I find a complete guide about this? What is selenium? I don't know so much about coding but I need to solve a similar problem. Please help me.