# Writing a script to download files from a website? (Python, Selenium(?))

Tags: python, ruby, selenium, web-scraping, webautomation

I am working on a web scraping project and would like to write a script to download multiple files from the following [site](http://war-on-ice.com/teambygame.html)).
I want to basically write a program which changes the date and a few other settings in the form, then clicks the download game table button and downloads the appropriate table. There is no API for this site so I THINK we actually have to click the button in order to initiate the necessary HTTP requests to download the file.

I am currently looking at using Selenium Bindings in Python to achieve this. (Though I would also consider solutions using other languages, particularly Ruby) Would this be possible with Selenium?  Where can I find information about automating downloading a file using a script?

Comment: Sigh... [try me](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-download-a-file-with-webdriver).

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by python selenium(download:pip install selenium).
first import webdriver from selenium.
To use chrome webdriver you have to download it first from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) or you can simply use firefox webdriver.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser=webdriver.Firefox()
```

then you need to find those field you can use any one of the below methods.if you get an id or name of field then it would be great else you have to use x-path

```
element = browser.find_element_by_id("field-id")
element = browser.find_element_by_name("fieldname")
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='field-id']")
```

if you are able to find it then now you can send input to that field by using

```
element.send_keys("Whatever you need to write")
```

do this for all input fields
then similarly find the submit button

```
element=browser.find_element_by_id("Submit")
```

to click the button

```
element.click()
```

to get details read the doc from [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/navigating.html#filling-in-forms).now since you want to do it multiple times try enclosing it inside function.and if there are many files you can multithread it.
hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response. I am going to try this out and see where it takes me. So I guess its just as simple as clicking  the button? I thought I might have to accept a download in the browser or do some additional programming to make sure the download runs smoothely

Comment: Please find an example code to download files at http://stackoverflow.com/a/35031322/2329061.

Comment: @user3037691 .after clicking the download link the downloading will start in browser itself if link provides a downloadable.In case if it prompts for manual saving, you can try the code mentioned in above comment .